# How can I loop over a list of dicts in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

How do I solve Ansible loop problem with file2 var?

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    file1: "file1.zip"
    file2: 
      - "file2_part1.zip"
      - "file2_part2.zip"
      - "file2_part3.zip"
    file3: "file3.zip"
    web:
      - link: "https://url.com/store1/{{ file1 }}"
      - link: "https://url.com/store2/{{ file2 }}"
      - link: "https://url.com/store3/{{ file3 }}"
  tasks:
    name: Download packages
    local_action:
      module: get_url
      url:   "{{ item }}"
      dest:  "/tmp"
    with_items: "{{ web.link  }}"
```

```
failed: [localhost] (item=https://url.com/store2/['file2_part1.zip', 'file2_part2.zip', 'file2_part3.zip']) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "dest": "/tmp", "elapsed": 0, "gid": 0, "group": "root", "item": "hhttps://url.com/store2/['file2_part1.zip', 'file2_part2.zip', 'file2_part3.zip']", "mode": "01777", "msg": "An unknown error occurred: URL can't contain control characters. \"/store2/['file2_part1.zip', 'file2_part2.zip', 'file2_part3.zip']\" (found at least ' ')", "owner": "root", "secontext": "system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0", "size": 4096, "state": "directory", "uid": 0, "url": "https://url.com/store2/['file2_part1.zip', 'file2_part2.zip', 'file2_part3.zip']"}
```

How can I write a task to iterates over the dictionary?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but local_action on a localhost target is non sense. Just use the `get_url` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I solve Ansible loop problem with file2 var?

Your data structure is definitely not adapted to your requirement. Here is a possible example of a more adapted one in the following playbook.

Must read to understand the below:

- [`subelements` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_filter.html)
- [ansible loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    downloads:
      - link_base: https://url.com/store1/
        files:
          - file1.zip
      - link_base: https://url.com/store2/
        files:
          - file2_part1.zip
          - file2_part2.zip
          - file2_part3.zip
      - link_base: https://url.com/store3/
        files:
          - file3.zip
  
  tasks:
    - name: Download packages
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: I would download file {{ item.0.link_base }}{{ item.1 }}
      loop: "{{ downloads | subelements('files') }}"
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [Download packages] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'link_base': 'https://url.com/store1/', 'files': ['file1.zip']}, 'file1.zip']) => {
    "msg": "I would download file https://url.com/store1/file1.zip"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'link_base': 'https://url.com/store2/', 'files': ['file2_part1.zip', 'file2_part2.zip', 'file2_part3.zip']}, 'file2_part1.zip']) => {
    "msg": "I would download file https://url.com/store2/file2_part1.zip"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'link_base': 'https://url.com/store2/', 'files': ['file2_part1.zip', 'file2_part2.zip', 'file2_part3.zip']}, 'file2_part2.zip']) => {
    "msg": "I would download file https://url.com/store2/file2_part2.zip"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'link_base': 'https://url.com/store2/', 'files': ['file2_part1.zip', 'file2_part2.zip', 'file2_part3.zip']}, 'file2_part3.zip']) => {
    "msg": "I would download file https://url.com/store2/file2_part3.zip"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'link_base': 'https://url.com/store3/', 'files': ['file3.zip']}, 'file3.zip']) => {
    "msg": "I would download file https://url.com/store3/file3.zip"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```